# Error when trying to insert data in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data in a database. I get this error:

> error getting data

This is my form code for inserting...

```
<body>

    <form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><b>Enter the data:</b></legend>
    <p>Pick a Date: <input type="date" id="datepicker" name="date" /></p>
        <p>SANC AMT
        <select name="f2" size="1">
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
            <option value="NO SANCTION">NO SANCTION</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select></p>

        <p>FORM SALE <select name="f3" size="1">
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
            <option value="NO SALE">NO SALE</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select> </p>
        <p>FORM CHAN <input type="text" name="f4"></p>
        <p>FORM SUB 1st <input type="text" name="f5"></p>
        <p>FORM REF <input type="text" name="f6"></p>
        <p>FORM REJ <input type="text" name="f7"></p>
        <p>F SUB 2nd <input type="text" name="f8"></p>
        <p>F SUB 3rd <input type="text" name="f9"></p>
        <p>FUEL <input type="text" name="f10"></p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>

    </fieldset>
    </form>


</body>
```

This is my php code for insertion inside same php file

```
<?php
        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        $db = mysql_select_db("proj",$conn);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $f2 = $_POST['f2'];
    $f3 = $_POST['f3'];
    $f4 = $_POST['f4'];
    $f5 = $_POST['f5'];
    $f6 = $_POST['f6'];
    $f7 = $_POST['f7'];
    $f8 = $_POST['f8'];
    $f9 = $_POST['f9'];
    $f10 = $_POST['f10'];

    $sql     = "INSERT into proj1 values('','$date','$f2','$f3','$f4','$f5', '$f6','$f7','$f8','$f9','$f10')";

    $query  = mysql_query($sql) or die('error getting data');

    if($query)
    {
        echo "<table align='center'>";
        echo '<h1 style="text-align:center;">Inserted</h1><br />';
        echo '<h3 style="text-align:center;"><i>You have inserted ....</i></h3>';
        echo '<tr><th>Date:</th><td> ' .$date. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>Sanc amt </th><td> ' .$f2. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>Form SALE</th><td>  ' .$f3. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>FORM CHan </th><td> ' .$f4. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>FORM Sub 1st </th><td> ' .$f5. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>FORM ref </th><td> ' .$f6. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>FORM rej</th><td> ' .$f7. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>F sub 2nd</th><td>  ' .$f8. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>F sub 3rd</th><td> ' .$f9. '</td><tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>FUEL</th><td> ' .$f10. '</td><tr>';
        echo "</table>";
    }
    }
 mysql_close($conn); ?>
```

This is my SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proj1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `sanc_amt` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_sale` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_chan` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_sub` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_ref` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_rej` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_sub2` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_sub3` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuel` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please provide the mysql error that you're getting. Just replace "die('error getting data');" with  "die(mysql_error());" and you should get the error message.

Comment: mysql_query failed try using `mysql_error`

Comment: Try `die(mysql_error)` as the or condition on your `mysql_query` call - a fixed error message isn't very useful when developing, especially as the database can tell you exactly what the problem was.

Comment: Thank you all i got error after mysql_error() inside die function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `id` field, in your statement you provide '' for id that can't be `NULL` and it's a `int`.

So in your table add `AUTO_INCREMENT` in `id` definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proj1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `sanc_amt` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_sale` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_chan` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_sub` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_ref` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `form_rej` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_sub2` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_sub3` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuel` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And in your query:

```
$sql="INSERT into proj1 (DATE, sanc_amt, form_sale, form_chan, form_sub, form_ref, form_rej, f_sub2, f_sub3, fuel) values('$date','$f2','$f3','$f4','$f5', '$f6','$f7','$f8','$f9','$f10')";
```

And should works.

Answer (score 0):

The error is you in your table.
You specified 'id' as not null and make it primary key too.

But you are trying to insert '' to id(Primary key)

Solution :
Remove not null for 'id' in the table `proj1` 
or make it auto increment